# Setup local virtual network with VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I want to setup a network for several VMs in VirtualBox which will satisfy the following conditions:

- Each VM must be reachable from the Host and have a fixed IP
- Each VM must reach host with a fixed IP
- Each VM must reach internet
- This setup must work regardless of how the Host access internet (it's a laptop, sometimes is on cable, sometimes in different WiFi networks).

I've tried bridged interfaces, but then the VMs addresses will be given by the Host's network, and in some WiFi setups will keep changing constantly, and that will break the setup.

Any suggestions on how to configure this?

Comment: Suggestions: Create two interfaces in each VM. One 'host-only interface' for talking to host and one 'NAT intreface' for Internet in VM. Two interfaces must be in different subnet.

Comment: How can that be done? I can only setup one interface in VBox, or am I missing something?

Comment: See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jk5Kfm2-Muk&feature=youtu.be) and this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251863).

Comment: Ok, then write your answer with details as possible, with network configurations, screenshots, which steps you've done etc. Also add my provided two links. I'll then delete the comments to keep it clean.

Comment: Ok. One more thing (I'll add to the question). I just realized that the host must also be accessible from the guests. Any idea on how to do that?